# cloud messaging not working with firebase in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am following this codelab tutorial- https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web#10
but i am facing problem in sending cloud messages with FCM
i am not getting permission to enable notification in my app

my js functions

```
async function saveMessagingDeviceToken() {
  try {
    const currentToken = await getToken(getMessaging());
    if (currentToken) {
      console.log('Got FCM device token:', currentToken);
      // Saving the Device Token to Cloud Firestore.
      const tokenRef = doc(getFirestore(), 'fcmTokens', currentToken);
      await setDoc(tokenRef, { uid: getAuth().currentUser.uid });

      // This will fire when a message is received while the app is in the foreground.
      // When the app is in the background, firebase-messaging-sw.js will receive the message instead.
      onMessage(getMessaging(), (message) => {
        console.log(
          'New foreground notification from Firebase Messaging!',
          message.notification
        );
      });
    } else {
      // Need to request permissions to show notifications.
      requestNotificationsPermissions();
    }
  } catch(error) {
    console.error('Unable to get messaging token.', error);
  };
}
// Requests permissions to show notifications.
async function requestNotificationsPermissions() {
  console.log('Requesting notifications permission...');
  const permission = await Notification.requestPermission();
  
  if (permission === 'granted') {
    console.log('Notification permission granted.');
    // Notification permission granted.
    await saveMessagingDeviceToken();
  } else {
    console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.');
  }
}
```

I have also correctly enabled FCM service in config file

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getMessaging } from 'firebase/messaging/sw';
import { getFirebaseConfig } from './firebase-config';

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(getFirebaseConfig());
getMessaging(firebaseApp);
console.info('Firebase messaging service worker is set up');
```

Can anyone please help me figure out the problem

I checked the occurences of this function in the index file and it is initialized well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a firebase-messaging-sw.js file at your root folder ?

As mentioned here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client?hl=fr&authuser=0

you can define it like that :

```html
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-app-compat.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-messaging-compat.js");

firebase.initializeApp({
  //YOUR_CONF
});
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```